# "Call to a member function .. on a non-object"

Tags: php, sql, authentication

[Hi, I am following this guide and copying exactly what is posted](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) (except the author forgot some curly brackets, and I changed passwords etc). My problem is in the register.inc.php file.

Here is the following error I receive when a user tries to register

> Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/ / /includes/register.inc.php on line 48

Line 48 of the file is

```
$stmt = $members_mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
```

Here is the entire register.inc.php file:

http://pastebin.com/YcQ7unb0 (It's not being properly formatted on this site)

Comment: At a quick glance the chances are you need to use `$mysqli->prepare` instead of `$members_mysqli->prepare` as it is used on line 30 of your code with a very similar SQL query

Comment: Take a look at the related questions..

Answer (score 1):

$members_mysqli is probably a typo.  It was never created.  You use another variable named $mysqli.  Maybe that's the one you meant to use.  Check your include files and make sure you actually instantiated $members_mysqli.

The "call to member function on non-object" error is thrown when you try to use an uncreated/uninstantiated variable as an object.

For example:

```
// create an object
$blah = new Blah();

// call a function on it
$blah->doSomething();

// no error, because $blah exists.  however, if my next line is:
$blue->doSomething();

// I'd get an error because $blue was never created
```

Comment: He's correct, from the code supplied, nowhere within it is `$members_mysqli` instantiated.