# Database Error in Code, possible mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication, mysqli

following on a bit from this person: ["Call to a member function .. on a non-object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507155/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object)

This is the code:

```
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error for EMAIL</p>';
    }

    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $members_mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this username already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error for USERNAME</p>';
    }

    // TODO:
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

        // Create salted password
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

        // Insert the new user into the database
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    }
}
}
```

I change the $stmt = $members_mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt); line to $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt); but still getting a database error around the area where the code was changed.

It manages to verify the email fine, but when it tries to do the username; it gives a database error (I'm guessing that the email is fine because it is first and doesn't throw the error).

I have printed the $stmt for both verification of email and username, the username does give a different result, which leads to make me believe that the members_mysqli might of been done on purpose? The code given by the print_r is:

```
mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 1 [field_count] => 1 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 ) 
mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 1 [field_count] => 1 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 2 )
```

If I read the code right, the Limit is supposed to be 1 but it has given a 2 causing the database error, how would I go around to fixing this or working out the problem?

Comment: What is the database error?

Comment: I see `$mysqli->prepare` and then I see `$members_mysqli->prepare` which DB connection are you using, both, one, none of the above? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: @hichris123 The error is the else message given from the code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I entered the code and it just gave the same output, and I'm using the $mysqli->prepare, which is near enough just the MySQL information (e.g user, pass, table)

Comment: So why do you have `$members_mysqli->`? Is that a seperate DB connection variable?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not sure if I explained it well, but the problem from the other thread was the code given had $members_mysqli-> which caused 'Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/ / /includes/register.inc.php on line 48', people wrote that it could be a mistype so I changed it to mysqli, causing this new error... 

$members_mysqli-> might be something that hadn't been coded properly though, I'm not sure. members is the name of the table used to hold the information

Comment: What does `var_dump($password);` yield?

Comment: It just dumps the password entered in hash form.    'string(128) "b5ea29bf7deec95dfb0ccc8b6127121cfe7001897338787c8b4f6240135d736d02e79a560f4ffaebc7415932fc67260e7da6645a4892556059ee2e9d400884e8"'

Comment: Sorry, I meant `$username`

Comment: @Fred-ii- The username I was registering with was john, so it gives: string(4) "john"

Comment: Might be a silly question but both the column exists (username and not Username) and the name `john` too?

Comment: Just 'username', john doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: There's the problem then. Your script fails because it doesn't exist (it's a non-object). You're not taking into account that it doesn't. Enter `john` in the `username` column then, your script should then echo success.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, it did it fine with the email address and it doesn't exist? shouldn't it carry on if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Conditional statements should take into account if it both exists and if it doesn't. So when you're checking if it exists, you're getting back an `Database error for USERNAME` when it doesn't or you're getting the error message `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`?

Comment: I added john into the database and it's given me the right "A user with this username already exists" message. And I found out the problem I was having, there was a } in the wrong place.

Comment: Ah, great. Problem solved then. Which `}` was it? One that should have been after `$stmt->store_result();`?

Comment: Actually I see it now, you had a missing brace `}` after `$error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's the one! Thanks for the help :-) If you want, you can write the answer as it doesn't let newbies do it for another 8 hours

Comment: You're welcome. I will formulate an answer and post it in a minute or so.

Comment: It has been done. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing brace `}` that should be placed after

```
$error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';
```

which causes your conditional statement to fail. This for `if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {`

```
// check existing username
$prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $members_mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // A user with this username already exists
  $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';

    } // <-- right there

} else {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error for USERNAME</p>';
}
```